# Retrieving data from famous movie websites

Tags: c++

I am currently prototyping a university project and I need to know whether it is possible to fetch the rating of a movie from [imdb.com](http://imdb.com) or [rottentomatoes.com](http://rottentomatoes.com), using C++. If so, would that be possible to somehow search for that rating based on a title alone?

Comment: Neither of them have public APIs. You can scrape the data but that might cause issues with licensing. IMDbs Database is publicly available too IIRC but then again, you'll have to look into their licensing policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to use website `https://www.omdbapi.com/`.
You can query informations about movie just by sending HTTP request. Site will return JSON with informations about movie.

Example:

HTTP request
`https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Ghost`
will return JSON

`{
  "Title":"Ghost",
  "Year":"1990",
  "Rated":"PG-13",
  "Released":"13 Jul 1990",
  "Runtime":"127 min",
  "Genre":"Drama, Fantasy, Romance",
  "Director":"Jerry Zucker",
  "Writer":"Bruce Joel Rubin",
  "Actors":"Patrick Swayze, Demi Moore, Whoopi Goldberg, Tony Goldwyn",
  "Plot":"After a young man is murdered, his spirit stays behind to warn his lover of impending danger, with the help of a reluctant psychic.",
  "Language":"English",
  "Country":"USA",
  "Awards":"Won 2 Oscars. Another 16 wins & 22 nominations.",
  "Poster":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU0NzQzODUzNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjc5NTYxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings":[
    {
      "Source":"Internet Movie Database",
      "Value":"7.0/10"
    },
    {
      "Source":"Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value":"74%"
    },
    {
      "Source":"Metacritic",
      "Value":"52/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore":"52",
  "imdbRating":"7.0",
  "imdbVotes":"160,136",
  "imdbID":"tt0099653",
  "Type":"movie",
  "DVD":"24 Apr 2001",
  "BoxOffice":"N/A",
  "Production":"Paramount Pictures",
  "Website":"N/A",
  "Response":"True"
}`

To send HTTP request you may use Boost Asio or cpp-netlib (https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!